# Why List is not paged in client side but show all results?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm experiencing a very strange bug. Basically in the controller, when I contact the "/categories/page/{pageNum}" endpoint passing a keyword as a parameter, the client returns the paginated list. When instead, I contact the "/categories" endpoint in the client, the list is not paginated but returns all the results. Below I show you the classes inherent in the execution of all the code.

```
@GetMapping("/categories")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('Admin', 'Editor')")
    public String listFirstPage(@Param("sortDir") String sortDir, Model model) {
        if(sortDir == null)
            sortDir = "asc";
        return listByPage(1, "name", null, model);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/categories/page/{pageNum}")
    public String listByPage(@PathVariable("pageNum")int pageNum,
            @Param("sortDir") String sortDir,
            @Param("keyword") String keyword,
            Model model) {
        if (sortDir == null || sortDir.isEmpty()) {
            sortDir = "asc";
        }
        
        CategoryPageInfo pageInfo = new CategoryPageInfo();
        List<Category> listByPage = service.listByPage(pageInfo, pageNum, sortDir, model, keyword);
        
         long startCount = (pageNum - 1) * CategoryService.ROOT_CATEGORY_PER_PAGE + 1;
         long endCount = startCount + CategoryService.ROOT_CATEGORY_PER_PAGE -1;
         if(endCount > pageInfo.getTotalElement())
             endCount = pageInfo.getTotalElement();
        
        String reverseSortDir = sortDir.equals("asc") ? "desc" : "asc";
        
        model.addAttribute("totalPages", pageInfo.getTotalPages());
        model.addAttribute("totalElements", pageInfo.getTotalElement());
        model.addAttribute("currentPage", pageNum);
        model.addAttribute("pageNum", pageNum);
        model.addAttribute("sortField", "name");
        model.addAttribute("sortDir", sortDir);
        model.addAttribute("keyword", keyword);
        model.addAttribute("categories", listByPage);
        model.addAttribute("startCount", startCount);
        model.addAttribute("endCount", endCount);
        model.addAttribute("reverseSortDir", reverseSortDir);
        return "categories/categories.html";
    }
```

```
package com.shopme.admin.category;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import com.shopme.admin.FileUploadUtil;
import com.shopme.common.entity.Category;

import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class CategoryService {
    public static final int ROOT_CATEGORY_PER_PAGE = 4;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository repo;

    public List<Category> listByPage(CategoryPageInfo pageInfo, int pageNum, String sortDir, Model model,
            String keyword) {
        Sort sort = Sort.by("name");

        if (sortDir.equals("asc")) {
            sort = sort.ascending();
        } else if (sortDir.equals("desc")) {
            sort = sort.descending();
        }

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNum - 1, ROOT_CATEGORY_PER_PAGE, sort);

        Page<Category> categoriesPage = null;

        if (keyword != null && !keyword.isEmpty()) {
            categoriesPage = repo.search(keyword, pageable);
        } else {
            categoriesPage = repo.findRootCategoriesPage(pageable);
        }

        List<Category> rootCategories = categoriesPage.getContent();

        pageInfo.setTotalElement(categoriesPage.getTotalElements());
        pageInfo.setTotalPages(categoriesPage.getTotalPages());

        if (keyword != null && !keyword.isEmpty()) {
            List<Category> searchResult = categoriesPage.getContent();
            for(Category category : searchResult) {
                category.setHasChildren(category.getChildren().size() > 0);
            }
            
            return searchResult;
            
        } else {
            return listHierarchicalCategories(rootCategories, sortDir);
        }
        
        
    }

    private List<Category> listHierarchicalCategories(List<Category> rootCategories, String sortDir) {
        List<Category> listHierarchicalCategories = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Category rootCategory : rootCategories) {
            listHierarchicalCategories.add(Category.copyFull(rootCategory));

            Set<Category> children = sortSubCategory(rootCategory.getChildren(), sortDir);

            for (Category subCategory : children) {
                String name = "--" + subCategory.getName();
                listHierarchicalCategories.add(Category.copyFull(subCategory, name));

                listSubHierarchicalCategories(listHierarchicalCategories, subCategory, 1, sortDir);
            }
        }

        return listHierarchicalCategories;
    }

    private void listSubHierarchicalCategories(List<Category> listHierarchicalCategories, Category parent, int subLevel,
            String sortDir) {
        Set<Category> children = sortSubCategory(parent.getChildren(), sortDir);
        int newSubLevel = subLevel + 1;

        for (Category subCategory : children) {
            StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < newSubLevel; i++) {
                name.append("--");
            }
            name.append(subCategory.getName());

            listHierarchicalCategories.add(Category.copyFull(subCategory, name.toString()));

            listSubHierarchicalCategories(listHierarchicalCategories, subCategory, newSubLevel, sortDir);
        }

    }
```

In my opinion i think i need to limit the search results also in all SubCategory that i add

Comment: This is not a solution to your problem, but you can simplify this greatly by adding `Pageable pageable` as a parameter to the endpoint method, and Spring will automatically create it from the query parameters "size", "pageNumber", "sort=name,asc", etc. You can then pass that same pageable object to your repository as long as it is a descendant of `PagingAndSortingRepository`.  This may simplify your code enough to eliminate some errors.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but it not solved main problem, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not passing the pageNumber when you are using "/categories" to fetch record it will print all records you have to set default value as attribute so that if you are not passing the value it is still limited by that value use following code:-

```
@PathVariable(value="pageNum",defaultValue="1",reuired="false")int 
pageNum)
```

Comment: is that solve your problem?